# Making a probability tree using tikzpicture / forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I want to create a probability tree using either `tikzpicture` or forest. I have experimented a little bit with both, but I'm running into some trouble with both of the programs.

First, I have my code for `tikzpicture` that I want to create:

```
![\begin{tikzpicture}\[grow=right, sloped\]
\node\[bag\] {(1, 1)}
child {
    node\[bag\] {($\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{2}$)}        
        child {
            node\[\] {($\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{1}{4}$)}
            edge from parent
            node\[above\] {$T$}
            node\[below\]  {$\frac{1}{2}$}
        }
        child {
            node\[\] {(1, 1)}
            edge from parent
            node\[above\] {$H$}
            node\[below\]  {$\frac{1}{2}$}
        }
        edge from parent 
        node\[above\] {$T$}
        node\[below\]  {$\frac{1}{2}$}
}
child {
    node\[bag\] {(2, 2)}        
    child {
            node\[\] {(1, 1)}
            edge from parent
            node\[above\] {$T$}
            node\[below\]  {$\frac{1}{2}$}
        }
        child {
            node\[\] {(4, 4)}
            edge from parent
            node\[above\] {$H$}
            node\[below\]  {$\frac{1}{2}$}
        }
    edge from parent         
        node\[above\] {$H$}
        node\[below\]  {$\frac{1}{2}$}
};
\end{tikzpicture}][1]
```

Next, I have my forest code:

```
\begin{forest} 
  for tree={grow=0,l=3cm,anchor=west,child anchor=west}
    [{$(1, 1)$}
      [{$(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$}
        [{$(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4})$}]
        [{$(1,1)$}]
      ]
      [{$(2, 2)$}
        [{$(1,1)$}]
        [{$(4,4)$}]
      ]
    ]
\end{forest}
```

I like the `tikzpicture` style and spacing very much, except I would love to be able to have labels along the bottom that say "$t=0$", "$t=1$", "$t=2$", etc. that are in a single horizontal line? Is there a way to do this in `tikzpicture`? I want the labels like in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166274/problem-with-probability-tree).

Regarding the forest code, I think that the diagram is too condensed and squished together. Is there a way to make it more spread out, like the `tikzpicture`? Also, is there a method to create labels "$t=0$", "$t=1$", "$t=2$", etc. as above?

[image]

The above graph is my `tikzpicture` and the below is my forest.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and combine your code fragments into a single compilable document? This will make it easier for others to play with the code.

Comment: The question you linked to with the labels you want has an answer which uses `forest` so you can adapt that to do the labelling. Try `fit=rectangle` or `fit=band` for a less compact tree. (Page 29.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to space out the tree in `forest` is to increase the minimum distance between the siblings. As mentioned above, `fit` can also be used to adjust the spread.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={grow=0,l=3cm,anchor=west,child anchor=west, s sep+=10pt}
    [{$(1, 1)$}, name=t0
      [{$(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$}
        [{$(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4})$}, name=bot]
        [{$(1,1)$}]
      ]
      [{$(2, 2)$}, name=t1
        [{$(1,1)$}]
        [{$(4,4)$}, name=t2]
      ]
    ]
    \coordinate [below=of bot] (coord);
    \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
      \node at (coord -| t\i) {$t=\i$};
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: Spacier tree]